# R: Match closest observation of variable from df_x before and after date of df_y (based on date & UID)

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, dplyr, merge

I have **two data frames**, each containing multiple observations of the same variables for several unique user IDs but each data frame **recording different variables**.

Head of **DF_x**:

| UID | BoughtBanana? | TypeOfBanana | Date_DF_x |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1231 | 0 | green | 2011-12-02 |
| 1253 | 0 | yellow | 2012-02-05 |
| 1231 | 1 | yellow | 2011-11-02 |
| 1243 | 1 | green | 2014-10-07 |

Head of **DF_y**:

| UID | LifeHappiness | Date_DF_y |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1253 | 3 | 2011-12-14 |
| 1231 | 5 | 2012-02-02 |
| 1243 | 2 | 2011-11-11 |
| 1231 | 7 | 2014-09-04 |

**What I want to do: Matching based on UID & date, mutating to new variables**

I'd like to attach the closest life happiness scores available for a certain UID **before** and **after** each observation in DF1 - but only if the dates do not differ by more than 21 days (both before and after), otherwise it should be coded as NA. The outcome should look like this, with the last two columns filled with the matched values respectively NAs:

| UID | BoughtBanana? | TypeOfBanana | Date_DF_x | ClosestLifeHappinessBefore | ClosestLifeHappinessAfter |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1231 | 0 | green | 2011-12-02 |  |  |
| 1253 | 0 | yellow | 2012-02-05 |  |  |
| 1231 | 1 | yellow | 2011-11-02 |  |  |
| 1243 | 1 | green | 2014-10-07 |  |  |

Anyone able to help? I was thinking about for-looping an if-else-statement like this (Example for "ClosestLifeHappinessBefore"), but I'm not able to express that correctly:

```
for(i in DF_x) {
  mutate(ClosestLifeHappinessBefore = ifelse(DF_y$UID == DF_x$UID & as.numeric(difftime(DF_y$Date_DF_y, DF_x$Date_DF_x, units = "days") > 0) & (as.numeric(difftime(DF_y$Date_DF_y, DF_x$Date_DF_x, units = "days") < 21)), DF_y$LifeHappiness, NA)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach to doing the 'closest date before' part. You can adapt it to produce the after part:

```r
output = DF_x %>%
  left_join(DF_y, by = "UID") %>%

  # Y dates after X dates become NA
  mutate(Date_DF_y = ifelse(Date_DF_x <= Date_DF_y, NA, Date_DF_y)) %>%
  # closest Y date for each X date
  group_by(UID, Date_DF_x) %>%
  mutate(closest_date_y = max(Date_DF_y)) %>%
  # keep only record with closes date
  filter(Date_DF_y == closest_date_y) %>%

  # calculate number of days difference
  mutate(days_diff = Date_DF_y - Date_DF_x) %>%
  # NA if days too far apart
  mutate(LifeHappiness = ifelse(days_diff > 21, NA, LifeHappiness)
```

The key idea is to join all the records, use all the records to determine which is the closest date before, and then filter to the join to this date.